# Want to generate MAP key for PHP application

Tags: php, google-maps

I am maintaining an old MAP based Web application written in PHP. Somehow it's Map key expires. When I generate a new Key it is much shorter and does not work.

```
previous key":  ABQIAAAAH97iKOQ_8y9DN0H9FfYCUhRiOZYK68FL-ce9qG_lfib2BSFj1RRMsxtkwMFN066Xtiwy-rV3-U6wbA

current key: AIzaSyCUS8VQnps6ZaXSD0evvjipehnXeLsLD2c
```

Am I doing anything wrong?

Comment: Where are you generating the key, and where are you using the key?

Comment: i am generation key in console account.
https://code.google.com/apis/console/

and using it in my home page with liek this :
    
    <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps?file=api&amp;v=2&amp;sensor=true&amp;key=ABQIAAAAPdCaMpX-AZEa80Znz16QJhSoxOjycilwGNhSM5MPnu1M7uI_QxRv6K2NFEyEwN9_Z2a7_kTQwGzzNg" type="text/javascript"></script>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

v2 keys are no longer available.  You can only create v3 keys.  They should work for v2 maps (however v2 maps are deprecated and may not work after November 19, 2013).

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/v2/reference

> Note: The Google Maps JavaScript API Version 2 was officially deprecated on May 19, 2010. 
>   The original deprecation period has been extended from May 19, 2013 until November 19, 2013. 
>   As of this date, all applications requesting v2 will be served a special, wrapped version of 
>   the v3 API instead. We expect this wrapped version of the API will work for most simple 
>   maps, but we strongly encourage you to migrate your code to version 3 of the Maps JavaScript 
>   API before this date.